# azure workbook, create table with jquery

Tags: azure, azure-monitor-workbooks

I have table (data)

```
SWFLogOSot_CL
```

and I'm trying to see count of two columns:

```
values_in_use_connections_d
values_available_connection_d
```

I've done this:

```
union withsource="SWFLogOSot_CL" *
| summarize AvaibleConn = count() by ColumnName="values_available_connection_d"
```

This works, but shows count of just one column:

[image]

Does please anyone knows, how to add both `values_in_use_connections_d` and `values_available_connection_d`?

Thank you

Edit 1:
To add to the information, what I'm trying.
I tried this

```
union withsource="SWFLogOSot_CL" *
| summarize AvaibleConn = count() by ColumnName="values_available_connection_d", InUseConn = count() by ColumnName="values_in_use_connections_d"
```

to add another column with new data from the table, but I got a message
**Query could not be parsed at '=' on line [3,49]
Token: '=' Line: 3 Postion: 49**

so unfortunately I still can't get 2x columns (the number of them) from SWFLogOSot_CL into one table

Edit 2:

with

```
let availableData = 
    union withsource="SWFLogOSot_CL" *
    | summarize Conn1 = count() by ConnectionType = "Available", ColumnName = "values_available_connection_d";

let inUseData = 
    union withsource="SWFLogOSot_CL" *
    | summarize Conn2 = count() by ConnectionType = "InUse", ColumnName = "values_in_use_connections_d";
```

im able to get two variables.

But im not sure how to display them

Comment: To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.

Comment: It will be good if you can share sample data and expected output

Comment: Do you want to count the distinct values in those two columns?

Comment: I planned to show both values in a graph (pie chart)

Answer (score 1):

do you mean "count of distinct values in 2 columns?"

using "count" as you're using it would just return the same number as the number of rows you have.

if so,

```
SWFLogOSot_CL
| summarize 
    InUseConnections=dcount(values_in_use_connections_d), 
    AvailableConnnections=dcount(values_available_connection_d)
```

Otherwise, it would be more helpful to see a more complete example, like

- the table has this structure
- and pretend it has these N rows
- and i want to get a grid out that has this structure
- and has these M rows as results

(also unclear why the tilte has anything to do with `jQuery`?

Comment: I wrote jquery by mistake, I already deleted from keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your reply, I finally came up with this solution:

```
let data = SWFLogOSot_CL
| summarize values_available = sum(values_available_connection_d), values_in_use = sum(values_in_use_connections_d)
| project values_available, values_in_use;

data
| project label="Values Available", value=values_available
| union (data | project label="Values in Use", value=values_in_use)
| extend total = toscalar(data | summarize sum(values_available + values_in_use))
| extend percent = value * 100 / total
```

Thank you **very much** and sorry for the chaotically written question

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**